# Angularjs clicking on the already selected option change the ng-model value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select

I am currently having a select with a data-ng-options :

```
  <select data-ng-model='myValue'>
    <option value=''> Default </option>
    <option data-ng-repeat="i in item" value='{$ i.value $}'>Option</option>
  </select>
```

What I want to achieve is when the Default option is already selected in the dropbox, I would like to be able to click on it again and trigger the change of value (myValue taking the default value ('')).
It doesn't seem to work when the option is already the one selected in the dropbox, how can I change this ?

Comment: How about `<option value='' ng-click="emptyValue()">Default</option>` and in controller: `$scope.emptyValue = function(){ $scope.myValue = ''; }`

Answer (score 0):

This will wokr for you...
I hope so :)

```
<select data-ng-model='myValue' ng-change="change()">
    <option value=''> Default </option>
    <option data-ng-repeat="i in item">{{i}}</option>
 </select>
```

---

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.item = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    $scope.myValue = '';

    $scope.change = function() {
        console.log("change");
        alert("Change to: " + $scope.myValue);
    };

}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/13847)

Comment: Add minimum number of codes in the answer, if the url is break or migrate there will be no track for you answer. More over, in your answer if you select the `Default` option again, didnt get any alert.